# How can I have a line gap between the question and the answer (Tkinter-python)

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

Basically, I want a gap of a line between the question and the answer. Also, how could I change the colour text on the answer part (to a red one)  Example below.

**Question 1**

**Answer 1**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Flashcard Revision")
root.geometry("700x500")
root.config(bg = "#3062C7")
i = 0
k = -1

def question():
    clear()
    global my_text, f, q_lines, i, k
    f = open("Unit1 questions.txt")
    q_lines = f.readlines()
    my_text.insert(1.0, q_lines[i])
    k = k + 1
    i = i + 1

def clear():
    my_text.delete(1.0, END)

def answer():
    global my_text, f, a_lines, k
    g = open("Unit1 answers.txt")
    a_lines = g.readlines()
    my_text.insert(2.0, a_lines[k])
    

q_button = Button(root, text="Question", bg="white", activebackground="red", command=question).place(x=285, y=280)

a_button = Button(root, text = "Answer", bg="white", activebackground="red", command=answer).place(x=355, y=280)

my_text = Text(root, width=40, height=10, font=("Helvetica", 16))
my_text.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate two newline characters(`'\n'`) at the end of each question string to render the answer after leaving a line in the text widget.

*NOTE THIS LINE FROM THE [TK DOCS](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#:%7E:text=the%20string%20we%20supply%20can%20be%20multi%2Dline%20as%20well.%20To%20do%20this%2C%20simply%20embed%20%5Cn%20(newline)%20characters%20in%20the%20string%20at%20the%20appropriate%20locations.) -:*

> the string we supply can be multi-line as well. To do this, simply
> embed \n (newline) characters in the string at the appropriate
> locations.

Also note that, generally it is a good idea to use string based text indices, as in some cases a float might be insufficient in-order to describe the index.

```
my_text.insert('1.0', q_lines[i] + '\n\n')
```

Further to render the answer after a line gap, the text index for the insertion of the answer string must be `'3.0'` -:

```
my_text.insert('3.0', a_lines[k])
```

Also note, that it is always a good practice to close the file object once it has been used, using `f.close()`.

```
f = open(...) # Retrieve a file object.
some_random_string = f.readlines() # Use the file object.
f.close() # Close the file object after it's use is finished.
```

Alternatively you can also do `with open(...) as f :` and write the code that uses the file object `f` within the body of the `with` statement, this will automatically close the file object `f`, once it's use within `with`'s body is finished.

```
with open(...) as f : # Retrieve a file object named f
    some_random_string = f.readlines() # Use the file object.
# Out of with's body f is automatically closed by the with statement.
```

The full code with the above changes in place will look like this -:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Flashcard Revision")
root.geometry("700x500")
root.config(bg = "#3062C7")
i = 0
k = -1

def question():
    clear()
    global my_text, f, q_lines, i, k
    f = open("Unit1 questions.txt")
    q_lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    my_text.insert('1.0', q_lines[i] + '\n\n')
    k = k + 1
    i = i + 1

def clear():
    my_text.delete('1.0', END)

def answer():
    global my_text, f, a_lines, k
    g = open("Unit1 answers.txt")
    a_lines = g.readlines()
    g.close()
    my_text.insert('3.0', a_lines[k])

q_button = Button(root, text="Question", bg="white", activebackground="red", command=question).place(x=285, y=280)

a_button = Button(root, text = "Answer", bg="white", activebackground="red", command=answer).place(x=355, y=280)

my_text = Text(root, width=40, height=10, font=("Helvetica", 16))
my_text.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

**OUTPUT(Tested assuming `q_lines = ['question1', 'question2', 'question3']` and `a_lines = ['answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3']`)** -:

[image: OUTPUT]

**CODE USED FOR TESTING OUTPUT -:**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Flashcard Revision")
root.geometry("700x500")
root.config(bg = "#3062C7")
i = 0
k = -1

def question():
    clear()
    global my_text, f, q_lines, i, k
    q_lines = ['question1', 'question2', 'question3']
    my_text.insert('1.0', q_lines[i] + '\n\n')
    k = k + 1
    i = i + 1

def clear():
    my_text.delete('1.0', END)

def answer():
    global my_text, f, a_lines, k
    a_lines = ['answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3']
    my_text.insert('3.0', a_lines[k])
    

q_button = Button(root, text="Question", bg="white", activebackground="red", command=question).place(x=285, y=280)

a_button = Button(root, text = "Answer", bg="white", activebackground="red", command=answer).place(x=355, y=280)

my_text = Text(root, width=40, height=10, font=("Helvetica", 16))
my_text.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**NOTE:**

- For more information about text widget indices refer to [this](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/text-index.html).
- For a proper guide on how to handle file objects refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).